# Google chrome notifciations icons without 'web_accessible_resources'

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, icons

I'm currently working on a google chrome extension which needs to use notifications.

It's meant to extract an image from a site (got that part), upload it to imgur and then use it  as the icon for the notification. My problem is:

All icons have to be listed under 'web_accessible_resources' before being used in a notification. However, my problem is that I create the icon while the extension is already running and I therefore cannot add it to the manifest.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a [data URI](http://www.phpied.com/data-urls-what-are-they-and-how-to-use/). This is extra text to reach the 30-character minimum.